# NodeJS - socket hang up error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets

I am sending more than 50 requests to a server using node.js. However after 20-30 requests, I am getting a socket hang up error.

Error --

```
    Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1568:23)
    at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: Maybe your requests take too much time

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, looks like your backend server is hanging up the socket, either due to timeout or capacity. Can you throttle the requests you are sending? Using a library like async (with Limit method) might help you throttle the connections in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:
 This **could be** a problem caused by **Node** firing its **GC** and freezing all operations, which results in unpredictable occasional "socket hang up" errors.

I experienced a similar situation. I start a bunch of server calls wrapped in promises that run in parallel and then have a loop with a [sleep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/system-sleep) that check periodically for their completion. I observe the following pattern:

- The calls complete promptly for some time
- then there is a slow-down
- then eventually some "socket hang up" errors
- then server calls continue promptly

This pattern repeats continuously. The DataDog stats on the server I call does not show variations in latency that could be a primary cause, so my conclusion is - it is something on the Node app side.

If the problem is due to GC - that is a bad news, cause GC is usually referred to as "Magic" :). You can't predict, when and how deep it goes.

HTH